# Porting winform application to run on raspberry PI

Tags: c#, winforms, iot, windows-10-iot-core, raspberry-pi3

I have a c# winform application that I want to port to run on my new Raspberry PI 3. I'm in moaning mode because I thought that my app would just run. That is not the case at all. My winform app uses quart. net, the aforge library and common .net libraries such as `system.configuration`.
I though I would start with my logging class as someone had mentioned that non UI code should be easy to convert if anything needed changing at all.
This looks like I'm going to have to reinvent the wheel. To be specific for startes have a look at the function below. Any code that uses `system.configuration` will not work.
Is there any easier way of getting my app to work or do I have to literally convert almost all my code. Is the aforge library even going to work on the PI?
Is quart.net going to work?
Right now I feel like giving up and buying a small windows PC that runs "proper" windows.

C# Winform Code

```
class Logging
{

    public void Write_To_Log_File(String Message, String Procedure, String Error_Code, String Error_String)
    {
        try
        {
            // If the log file is bigger than allowed size then archive
            if (File.Exists(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"]))
            {

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"]);
                if (file.Length > Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileLogSizeLimit"]))
                {
                    // Rename the file
                    File.Move(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"], @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"] + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now) + ".csv");
                }

            }
            // If log file does not exist then create it and add the headers
            if (File.Exists(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"]))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the file
                System.IO.File.Create("LogSavePath");
                // Add data
                string[] Headers = { "Time" + "," + "_Message" + "," + "Procedure" + "," + "Error_Code" + "," + "Error_String" };
                System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"], Headers);
            }
            if (File.Exists(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"]))
            {
                string[] Log = { DateTime.Now.ToString() + "," + Message + "," + Procedure + "," + Error_Code + "," + Error_String };
                System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogSavePath"], Log);
            }

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is likely going to need some rewrite, as Rasberry only support mono environment, not the microsoft .net framework. Also, any library that is not pcl compliant will not work either. Good news for you is that Quartz.net and Aforge are both supported, as I've read.

Comment: Windows IoT edition should work on the board, but that means a change of OS. If you don't want that l, as the other comment indicates, you might check out Mono or .NET Core. But WinForms is probably not going to work very well due to the known issues.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft launched a Windows 10 IoT Core Porting Tool for this purpose. This can assist you in migrating from Win32 apps and libraries to Windows 10 IoT Core apps. More details here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/tools/iotapiportingtool

Comment: @user1438082 Reminder: please provide an answer if you're able to solve your issue, or mark one of the answers as accepted it it solves your issue. Thank you.